# What's a clean way to find (up to) 3x3 squares within a 6x6 grid?

Tags: 2d, grid

I have a 6x6 grid where every cell have a color property (simply integer value).

Player can change one cell at a time to form rectangles of the same color inside of the grid. New rectangles can only be 2x2, 3x2, 2x3 and 3x3 in size.

Is there a cleaner way to find those rectangles rather than having to manually search for `[i][j]`, `[i+1][j]`, `[i][j+1]` and `[i+1][j+1]` (et cetera) color matches?

Comment: Have a look at this as it may help http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: @Savlon A recursive search radiating out from the clicked point is exactly how I would solve this. Flood fill is a great example of a very similar algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If your shapes never get bigger than 3x3, your described approach should be sufficiently fast. A 3x3 maximum square means that whenever a player changes a tile's color, you only need to search two tiles in all directions (that is, a 5x5 search space). That's a total of 24 checks in the worst case (you don't need to check the center), which is not *that* taxing. Especially since the overall size of your grid means you will short-circuit out of many of those checks anyway (since they'd be out of bounds).

A potential optimization is to track the state of "partially assembled" squares as they are built. This reduces the number of checks you generally need to make to approximately 8 (the eight surrounding tiles of the clicked tile) to see if the clicked tile should be added to an existing potential solution, and whatever checks you need to see if a potential solution has just become valid (probably two or three more `if`s, to check it horizontal and vertical bounds).

However, this approach not only requires more memory but also requires a way for you to tell if a given tile is part of an existing potential solution, which is generally efficiently done with some kind of spatial partitioning technique. It is thus much more complex for what is a questionable performance gain at the scale you are working at.